# Eclipse deleted R File after clean

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to clean my project through Project->Clean and then suddenly all my R.java files in all my projects have been deleted. I don't know how to regenerate it now because I have hundreds of errors now...

How do I get my R.java files back?!

Comment: Solve the tiniest errors hiding in one or more of your xml files (every single xml file could be affected, also strings.xml). Check that your resource files don't contain invalid characters, such as UpperCase letters or hyphens. Restart Eclipse. Project/Clean.

Comment: not sure why but eclipse is acting so weird. it has cpu 90% and doesn't even have the adt plugin anymore -.-

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me yesterday, there are a few options you can try.

First try building the project again.

If that fails, try removing the `gen` file in eclipse and clean again

If that fails, try checking your `xml` files if there is any error

If everything fails, create a new project and copy-paste all `layouts`/`src` files to the new project.

EDIT:
I searched for this yesterday, and I tried every possible solution, but only creating a new project helped.

Answer (score 0):

Do follwing tasks:-

- If there are any errors in the layout or any resource files there
  will be no build happening and the `R.java` file will not be created.
- Please solve the errors and then try to clean the project.

  Or If no resource errors then try this step also In Eclipse :

  1. Select Help > check Updates.
  2. Select the Installed Software tab.
  3. Click Update.

  If an update for ADT is available, select it and clickFinish. Restart
  Eclipse.
- Right click on your project in Package explorer in Eclipse. You will
  get a number of options. Go to Android Tools-> Fix Project Properties
  so see if that helps.
- You should have errors indicating that R cannot be resolved to a
  variable. Right click on your project from the Package Explorer and
  select Build Project. Be sure Build Automatically option is turned
  off (uncheck in Project > Build Automatically).

Comment: my resource files don't contain any errors but my java files do because the R.java is missing! :/

Comment: @Davlog try to kill adb

Answer (score 0):

R.java files are generated automatically by Eclipse. Check if you have **Project > Build Automatically** checked or not. If not, check it and it should resolve your issue. Alternatively, check your project for other errors, preventing the R.java files form being generated.

If the issue still persists, try restarting Eclipse.